# How to fix adb: error: cannot bind listener: Operation not permitted react-native?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, react-native

I'm using Android Studio version 3.4.2, the latest, on Ubuntu 18.04LTS trying to run a react-native app in the emulator(NEXUS 5X API 29).

When I run 
`react-native run-android`

I get this

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 54s
27 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 25 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
adb: error: cannot bind listener: Operation not permitted
warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": Command failed: /home/user/Android-SDK/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.albums/.MainActivity }
```

But the app doesn't run or start.

MY SDK LOCATION IS RIGHT **/home/user/Android-SDK**

My *.bashrc* has these lines

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android-SDK
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

My *local.properties* file in my react-native android project directory has
`sdk.dir=/home/user/Android-SDK`

The SDK location is right in the android studio SDK manager as well.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with adb ,fixed it with `adb kill-server` then `adb root`.[solution link](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/437)

Also for some reason `react-native run-android` didn't work `react-native start` worked.